# Prettier extension - not format on lose focus

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

Is there a way to make the Prettier extension *not* format the code when losing focus from VS? Instead I would like it to only format when saving.

Comment: Post the relevant lines from your `settings.json`.

Comment: You were right it just saves on focus change so that's what caused it thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

open settings.json

"files.autoSave": "onFocusChange"

change to

"files.autoSave": "off"

or

"files.autoSave": "afterDelay"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).